# Are there hand tools for applying electrically conductive adhesive and stringing wire for manual wire bonding?

Tags: wirebonding

It would be handy to be able to place small jumpers on PCB without soldering.

Are there specialty hand tools for applying electrically conductive adhesive and stringing fine wire, sort of like a manual wire bonding technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are conductive adhesives that are useful in some specific circumstances, their electrical performance is far inferior to a soldered joint, and they are not suitable for general PCB repair or rework. Therefore, the kind of tools you are imagining have never been developed.